# "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (113)", MySQL Remote Connection Stopped Working After Server Change

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, remote-connection

Very very strange issue. So I have a website that accesses a database I have hosted on my VPS server by making a remote MySQL connection. On the VPS server I created a user with these permissions

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'myuser'@'%';
```

Then on my website I would connect to my VPS's database like so

```
$vpsCon = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

This was working 100% fine until I changed the hosting plan for my website. When I changed the hosting plan of my website when I try to connect to my VPS's database from my website I get the forllowing connection error

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (113)
```

Which is very very strange being that this was working just fine before I changed my hosting plan. The only thing that changed when I changed my website hosting plan was the IP that my website is hosting on, but that shouldn't matter being that I defined the VPS's MySQL user IP address as "%".

I've looked in my `my.cnf` because a I've found a lot of posts online saying that could be the issue but everything looks ok I think? Here's my `my.cnf` file for my VPS server that the database is hosted on

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

I'm just so confused, I've been trying for hours to fix this but haven't been able to come up with anything, this is messing with my whole website, no one can access my website anymore because of this issue and it's driving me crazy :/ any help or information would be highly highly appreciated! Thanks for your time.

Comment: Error 113 means that there's no route to the host... are you able to ping `x.x.x.x` from your new host's machine?

Comment: @csb Hm, I don't appear to be able to pin my VPS IP on my new website server host. I ran this PHP code

`exec("ping -n 3 $ip", $output, $status);
print_r($output);`

and it echoed "Array ( )"

Comment: @csb So that would indicate that my VPS is blocking the connection coming in from my webserver?

Comment: Probably the MySQL server's firewall blocks external connections (that wouldn't be uncommon for web hosting setups). The only other plausible issue I can think of is `x.x.x.x` is an internal IP?

Comment: Yup! If it's VPS, check `iptables` to see what the rules are like.

Comment: @csb Very strange when I ran the command `iptables -S` on my VPS it returned `-P INPUT ACCEPT -P FORWARD ACCEPT -P OUTPUT ACCEPT` meaning that there are no firewall rules. This is weird. Maybe could my webserver hosting be blocking connections to my VPS server? The strangest thing is this was working perfectly fine until I changed my web server hosting plan a few hours ago

Comment: that would be really really weird. Maybe try an outgoing connection to somewhere else - try even standard ports like 80? If it's also blocked, then problem lies with web host.